# Trying to generate friendly_id on rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-id

I keep getting this msg

```
$ rails generate friendly_id
```

> Running via Spring preloader in process 17863 Could not find generator
>   'friendly_id'. Maybe you meant 'channel', 'generator' or 'helper' Run
>   `rails generate --help` for more options.

**Gemfile**

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',        '5.0.0.1'
gem 'puma',         '3.4.0'
gem 'sass-rails',   '5.0.6'
gem 'uglifier',     '3.0.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.2.1'
gem 'jquery-rails', '4.1.1'
gem 'turbolinks',   '5.0.1'
gem 'jbuilder',     '2.4.1'
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.1.0' 
gem 'bootstrap', '~> 4.0.0.alpha5'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.11'
  gem 'byebug',  '9.0.0', platform: :mri
end

group :development do
  gem 'web-console',           '3.1.1'
  gem 'listen',                '3.0.8'
  gem 'spring',                '1.7.2'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '2.0.0'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem

gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

Comment: did you run `bundle install` after updating your `Gemifile`?

Answer (score 0):

You ensure your gem `friendly_id` is installed by running:

```
bundle install
```